# Is it possible to understand notification comes from which client?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I send notification one client to another successfully. With this method:

```
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
String yourMessage = "hello world";
push.setChannel("seconddevice");
push.setMessage(yourMessage);
push.sendInBackground();
```

my application:

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {
    String YOUR_APPLICATION_ID="xxx",YOUR_CLIENT_KEY="yyy";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Add your initialization code here
        Parse.initialize(this, YOUR_APPLICATION_ID, YOUR_CLIENT_KEY);


        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

        // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

        PushService.subscribe(this, DEVICE_NAME, NotificationBck.class);


    }

}
```

It works. But when I receive message in second device can I have which device send this notification?

Comment: you could use `push.setData()` and embed this information in a JSON object. AFAIK, `setChannel()` is a basic publish/subscribe model.

Comment: I want to use setchannel, it is possible to use setchannel and setdata together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Parse Android docs](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving/Android):

> The Intent object which is passed to the receiver contains an extras Bundle with two useful mappings. The `com.parse.Channel` key points to a string representing the channel that the message was sent on. The `com.parse.Data` key points to a string representing the JSON-encoded value of the "data" dictionary that was set in the push notification.

So, in your receiver, you'd be able to check the data (assuming you've set it when pushing):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
    String encodedJson = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data");

    Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel + " with:");
    JSONObject json = decodeJsonObjectFrom(encodedJson);
    logContentsOf(json);
}

private JSONObject decodeJsonObjectFrom(String encodedJson) {
    try {
        return new JSONObject(encodedJson);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return new JSONObject();
    }
}

private void logContentsOf(JSONObject json) {
    while (json.keys().hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) json.keys().next();
        Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + getStringFrom(json, key));
    }
}

private String getStringFrom(JSONObject json, String key) {
    try {
        return (String) json.get(key);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: where can I write this code? I did not have recive class?

Comment: when I paste this code in my class it gives this error :  **The method onReceive(Context, Intent) of type ParseStarterProjectActivity must override or implement a supertype method**

Comment: The docs I linked to demonstrate that you can set up an Android Receiver to intercept the Broadcast that's sent out when a Push notification is received.

Comment: I use MyCustomReceiver but it never receive anything , why I do not know :(

Comment: it is possible to get notification text without using jason data? just using setchannel? thanks in advance

Comment: I can t use custom receiver , I use default project from parse.com

Comment: please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730920/how-can-i-get-data-or-title-from-receiving-notifications

Comment: Why can't you use a custom receiver? In the worst case, you can extend the Parse one (remembering to call `super` where necessary, and omitting where safe)